# Preprocessing function doesn't change the dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I just made a function to preprocess my dataframe, however my function doesn't change anything, and I keep getting a KeyError: movement. What am I doing wrong?

(I copied in my code below)

```
data = []
with open("bird_jan25jan16.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            date_str, time, movement = line.split()
            dt_str = date_str + ' ' + time
            dt = datetime.strptime(dt_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            data.append([dt, movement])
        except ValueError:
            # Handle lines with unexpected format
            print(f"Ignoring line: {line}")

# Create a DataFrame from the data list
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Datetime", "Movement"])
print(df)
```

```
#Function for Movements diff > 4 
def replace_large_difference(df, movement):
    prev_value = df[movement].iloc[0]  # Get the initial value as the previous value
    for index, curr_value in enumerate(df[movement]):
        diff = curr_value - prev_value
        if diff > 8:
            df.loc[index, movement] = prev_value
        else:
            prev_value = curr_value
    return df

df_fixed = replace_large_difference(df, 'movement')

# Output the preprocessed DataFrame
print(df_fixed)
print(df_fixed.iloc[[1745]])
```

My dataframe for example looks like this, and I want the function to correct 20 to 70.

```
Datetime:                                   Movements:
2015-01-25 15:05:41.274647+01:00              70
2015-01-25 15:08:05.036915+01:00              20
2015-01-25 15:10:05.536604+01:00              70
...
2015-01-26 10:14:05.045367+01:00              76
2015-01-26 10:16:05.045367+01:00              77
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: the line  with "df=fixed...."

Comment: There is no such line

Comment: sorry I was to quick on the keyboard, i mean this line "df_fixed = replace_large_difference(df, 'movement')"

Comment: This means that the error is from running the function. Look carefully at the error code. What is the line that gives the error WITHIN the function?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that the Column of interest is titled 'movement'?  We could be of more help if you provided us with a sample data input of the df and what you expect out of your function.

Comment: @itprorh66 I tried to edit my question, in my data im tracking movements in a birds nest every 2 minutes. The movement column represents the total number of movements that day.

Answer (score 0):

Python is case sensitive.
Change the line:

```
df_fixed = replace_large_difference(df, 'movement')
```

to:

```
df_fixed = replace_large_difference(df, 'Movement')
```

Comment: I tried doing the following but then I get the error "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"

Comment: I think i solved it, forced the strings to become int